# Detect which toggleButotn was clicked

Tags: java, swing, button, awt, togglebutton

please help me to check what I have missed here. I am pulling my hair out of this and getting frustrated on this problems.

I have 30 JToggle and 2 buttons. When confirm button is pressed, I want to print out which toggleButton is clicked.

The output I get is always **No button clicked** even though I have clicked toggleButton.

[image]

```
public selectSeat(String title, String day, String time)
    {
        JPanel topPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 215));
        RectDraw rect= new RectDraw();
        rect.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3,25)); 
        topPanel.add(rect);

          JToggleButton[] ButtonList = new JToggleButton[30];

            JPanel ButtonPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,25,45,25)); // row,col,hgap,vgap
            for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {   
                int a=i+1;
                ButtonList[i]= new JToggleButton(""+a);
                ButtonPanel.add(ButtonList[i]);

            }

            JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,5,40,20));
            JButton cancel= new JButton("Cancel");
            JButton confirm= new JButton("Confirm");
            bottomPanel.add(cancel);
            bottomPanel.add(confirm);

           setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 45));
           add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
           add(ButtonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
           ButtonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
           bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 20, 20)); //top,left,bottom,right

           confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                   {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {
                   for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
                 {
                    if(ButtonList[i].isSelected())
                        {
                         System.out.println(i);
                        }                   
                   else  {
                       System.out.println("No button is clicked");
                   }
                    }    
        }
      });
               }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program currently gives output for each button as per your implementation hence when you click `confirm` it will print the number of toggled button and for all others it will print "No button is Clicked". If you just want to print the number of toggled button or "No button is clicked" if no button was toggled then you need to change your implementation to:

```
confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean buttonClicked = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    if (ButtonList[i].isSelected()) {
                        buttonClicked = true;
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
                if (!buttonClicked) {
                    System.out.println("No button is clicked");
                }
            }

        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you know how to increase the width of the rectangle and move it to below ?

Comment: Adjust your top panel's dimension

Comment: Please ask a new question displaying what's your need.